# concatenating mp3 in python usingn ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to concatenate mp3 in Python (windows 10) using ffmpeg but I'm getting this error (I've tried different alternatives, options ...). Any ideas? Any suggestion about other libraries?

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:sample0.mp3|sample1.mp3" -acodec  copy  output.mp3
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        ffmpeg -i "concat:sample0.mp3|sample1.mp3" -acodec  copy  output.mp3
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: ffmpeg command itself looks fine (but consider using concat demuxer instead). Verify that it works in `cmd`/PowerShell before adding to Python code.

Comment: Why do recommend the demux?  is it supposed to result in better audio quality?